# Regular expression not working on sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to use `sed` to change the format of decimal numbers in a large CSV file before importing it into a SQLite database. They all have two decimal places, may be negative use comma as a decimal separator and are therefore escaped with double quotes. I was trying the following:

```
sed 's/"(-?)([:digit:]+),([:digit:]{2})"/$1$2.$3/g' input.csv > output.csv
```

The regex seems to work on a text editor on a sample of the file, but when running it through `sed`, there are no changes to the original file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding -r flag to sed.

Comment: Seconded - in the format you've presented `-r` is a requirement. Depending on `sed` version `[:digit:]` may be a problem as well - `[0-9]` works just as well.

Comment: Apart from adding `-r`, i.e. enable extended regex syntax, change `[:digit:]` to `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting an error saying that `-r` is an illegal option.

Comment: `sed` only changes the original file if you use the "in-place" option `-i`. By default, it just prints the edited text to stdout.

Comment: Also, if you plan to use sed, you should probably go download and build the GNU version. You'll thank yourself later.

Comment: More generally, see [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since -r is unavailable, use this leaning toothpick forest:

```
sed 's/"\(-?[[:digit:]]\+\),\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)"/\1.\2/g' input.csv > output.csv
```

sed `-r` is a GNU extension. And sadly, most tools that use regular expressions implement the language slightly differently (grep/sed, awk, perl, ...)

Comment: Thanks, I also ended up downloading and building the GNU `sed` for future use!

Answer (score 0):

I find Perl's syntax simpler for such things (I am ignoring the quotes but you can add them if you wish):

```
perl -pe 's/(-*)(\d+),(\d{0,2})/$1$2.$3/g' input.csv > output.csv
```

You can also use the `-i` option to edit the original file directly.