# Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?

Tags: regular-expression, wildcards

I wrote a regular expression which works well in a certain program (grep, sed, awk, perl, python, ruby, ksh, bash, zsh, find, emacs, vi, vim, gedit, …). But when I use it in a different program (or on a different unix variant), it stops matching. Why?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Unfortunately, for historical reasons, different tools have slightly different regular expression syntax, and sometimes some implementations have extensions that are not supported by other tools. While there is a common ground, it seems like every tool writer made some different choices.

The consequence is that if you have a regular expression that works in one tool, you may need to modify it to work in another tool. The main differences between common tools are:

- whether the operators `+?|(){}` require a backslash;
- what extensions are supported beyond the basics `.[]*^$` and usually `+?|()`

In this answer, I list the [main standards](http://xkcd.com/927/). Check the documentation of the tools you're using for the details.

Wikipedia's [comparison of regular expression engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) has a table listing the features supported by common implementations.

### [Basic regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) (BRE)

Basic regular expressions are codified by the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03). It is the syntax used by **`grep`**, **`sed`** and **`vi`**. This syntax provides the following features:

- `^` and `$` match only at the beginning and end of a line.
- `.` matches any character (or any character except a newline).
- `[…]` matches any one character listed inside the brackets (character set). If the first character after the opening bracket is a `^`, the characters which are not listed are matched instead. To include a `]`, put it immediately after the opening `[` (or after `[^` if it's a negative set). If `-` is between two characters, it denotes a range; to include a literal `-`, put it where it can't be parsed as a range.
- Backslash before any of `^$.*\[` quotes the next character.
- `*` matches the preceding character or subexpression 0, 1 or more times.
- `\(…\)` is a syntactic group, for use with the `*` operator or backreferences and `\DIGIT` replacements.
- Backreferences `\1`, `\2`, … match the exact text matched by the corresponding group, e.g. `\(fo*\)\(ba*\)\1` matches `foobaafoo` but not `foobaafo`. There is no standard way to refer to the 10th group and beyond (the standard meaning of `\10` is the first group followed by a `0`).

The following features are also standard, but missing from some restricted implementations:

- `\{m,n\}` matches the preceding character or subexpression between *m* to *n* times; *n* or *m* can be omitted, and `\{m\}` means exactly *m*.
- Inside brackets, [character classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) can be used, for example `[[:alpha:]]` matches any letter. Modern implementations of [bracket expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05)) also include [collating elements](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html#tag_07_03_02_04) like `[.ll.]` and equivalence classes like `[=a=]`.

The following are common extensions (especially in GNU tools), but they are not found in all implementations. Check the manual of the tool you're using.

- `\|` for alternation: `foo\|bar` matches `foo` or `bar`.
- `\?` (short for `\{0,1\}`) and `\+` (short for `\{1,\}`) match the preceding character or subexpression at most 1 time, or at least 1 time respectively.
- `\n` matches a newline, `\t` matches a tab, etc.
- `\w` matches any word constituent (short for `[_[:alnum:]]` but with variation when it comes to localisation) and `\W` matches any character that isn't a word constituent.
- `\<` and `\>` match the empty string only at the beginning or end of a word respectively; `\b` matches either, and `\B` matches where `\b` doesn't.

Note that tools without the `\|` operator do not have the full power of regular expressions. Backreferences allow a few extra things that can't be done with regular expressions in the mathematical sense.

### [Extended regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended) (ERE)

Extended regular expressions are codified by the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04). Their major advantage over BRE is regularity: all standard operators are bare punctuation characters, a backslash before a punctuation character always quotes it. It is the syntax used by **`awk`**, **`grep -E`** or `egrep`, BSD (and GNU and soon POSIX) `sed -E` (formerly `sed -r` in GNU `sed`), and **bash / ksh93 / yash / zsh¹'s `=~`** operator. This syntax provides the following features:

- `^` and `$` match only at the beginning and end of a line.
- `.` matches any character (or any character except a newline).
- `[…]` matches any one character listed inside the brackets (character set). Complementation with an initial `^` and ranges work like in BRE (see above). [Character classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) can be used but are missing from a few implementations. Modern implementations also support equivalence classes and collating elements. A backslash inside brackets quotes the next character in some but not all implementations; use `\\` to mean a backslash for portability.
- `(…)` is a syntactic group, for use with `*` or `\DIGIT` replacements.
- `|` for alternation: `foo|bar` matches `foo` or `bar`.
- `*`, `+` and `?` matches the preceding character or subexpression a number of times: 0 or more for `*`, 1 or more for `+`, 0 or 1 for `?`.
- Backslash quotes the next character if it is not alphanumeric.
- `{m,n}` matches the preceding character or subexpression between *m* and *n* times (missing from some implementations); *n* or *m* can be omitted, and `{m}` means exactly *m*.
- Some common extensions as in BRE: `\DIGIT` backreferences (notably absent in awk except in the busybox implementation where you can use `$0 ~ "(...)\\1"`); special characters `\n`, `\t`, etc.; word boundaries `\b` and `\B`, word constituents `\b` and `\B`, …

### PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expressions)

PCRE are extensions of ERE, originally introduced by [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) and adopted by GNU **`grep -P`** and **many modern tools and programming languages**, usually via the [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) library. See the [Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) for nice formatting with examples. Not all features of the latest version of Perl are supported by PCRE (e.g. Perl code execution is only supported in Perl). See the [PCRE manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man3/pcresyntax.3.html) for a summary of supported features. The main additions to ERE are:

- `(?:…)` is a non-capturing group: like `(…)`, but does not count for backreferences.
- `(?=FOO)BAR` (lookahead) matches `BAR`, but only if there is also a match for `FOO` starting at the same position. This is most useful to anchor a match without including the following text in the match: `foo(?=bar)` matches `foo` but only if it's followed by `bar`.
- `(?!FOO)BAR` (negative lookahead) matches `BAR`, but there is not also a match for `FOO` at the same position. For example `(?!foo)[a-z]+` matches any lowercase word that does not start with `foo`; `[a-z]+(?![0-9)` matches any lowercase word that is not followed by a digit (so in `foo123`, it matches `fo` but not `foo`).
- `(?<=FOO)BAR` (lookbehind) matches `BAR`, but only if it is immediately preceded by a match for `FOO`. `FOO` must have a known length (you can't use repetition operators such as `*`). This is most useful to anchor a match without including the preceding text in the match: `(?<=^| )foo` matches `foo` but only if it's preceded by a space or by the beginning of the string.
- `(?<!FOO)BAR` (negative lookbehind) matches `BAR`, but only if it is not immediately preceded by a match for `FOO`. `FOO` must have a known length (you can't use repetition operators such as `*`). This is most useful to anchor a match without including the preceding text in the match: `(?<![a-z])foo` matches `foo` but only if it is not preceded by a lowercase letter.

### Emacs

[Emacs's syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html#Regexps) is intermediate between BRE and ERE. In addition to Emacs, it is the default syntax for `-regex` in GNU find. Emacs offers the following operators:

- `^`, `$`, `.`, `[…]`, `*`, `+`, `?` as in ERE
- `\(…\)`, `\|`, `\{…\}`, `\DIGIT` as in BRE
- [more backslash-letter sequences](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash); `\<` and `\>` for word boundaries; and more in recent versions of Emacs, that are often not supported in other engines with an Emacs-like syntax.

### Shell [globs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))

Shell globs (wildcards) perform pattern matching with a syntax that is completely different from regular expressions and less powerful. In addition to shells, these wildcards are available with other tools such as `find -name` and rsync filters. [POSIX patterns](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13) include the following features:

- `?` matches any single character.
- `[…]` is a character set as in common regular expression syntaxes. Some shells do not support character classes. Some shells require `!` instead of `^` to negate the set.
- `*` matches any sequence of characters (often except `/` when matching file paths; if `/` is excluded from `*`, then `**` sometimes includes `/`, but check the tool's documentation).
- Backslash quotes the next character.

Ksh offers [additional features](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#ksh_002dlike-Glob-Operators) which give its pattern matching the full power of regular expressions. These features are also available in bash after running `shopt -s extglob`. Zsh has a [different syntax](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) but can also support ksh's syntax after `setopt ksh_glob`.

---

<sup>¹ unless the `rematchpcre` option is enabled in `zsh` in which case `=~` uses PCREs there. ksh93's extended regexps also support some of perl's extended operators such as the look-around ones.</sup>

Comment: Other _rich_ REs you may want to mention are `vim`'s and AT&T libast (as in `ksh93`) ones.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Apart from vim, what program uses vim regexps? Apart from ksh, what program uses libast?

Comment: all of the AT&T tool set uses the AT&T REs (`grep`, `tw`, `expr`...). Except for `ksh`, that toolset is rarely found outside of AT&T though.

Comment: According to my understanding (and Wikipedia's), your term "Character class" actually refers to "POSIX character class" ... however, `regex(7)` agrees with you and calls `[these]` "bracket expressions" and (within "bracket expressions") `[:these:]` "character classes."  I'm not sure how to best address that.

Comment: Whatever you call them, they support ranges.  It's definitely worth noting that `-` specifies a range and should either be escaped, first (after the optional `^`), or last if it is to be taken literally.  (I've seen plenty of bugs stemming from e.g. `[A-z]` –note the change in case–, which matches characters of codes 65 to 122 and accidentally includes each of: `[\]^_\``.  I've also seen the valid yet confusing `[!-~]` to match all printable characters in ANSI, which I prefer to see as `[\x21-\x7e]`, which is at least straightforward in its action though confusing in a different dimension.)

Comment: @AdamKatz I don't understand the point of your comments. What I call a character class is what Wikipedia and POSIX call a character class. I didn't mention ranges; they are portable, but escaping `-` with a backslash isn't, and the influence of locales on ranges depends on the tool.

Comment: @AdamKatz I've added a discussion of ranges (but omitted the locale considerations which are off-topic here). Note that `[\x21-\x7e]` only works in engines where `\x` introduces a hexadecimal constants, which excludes most BRE and ERE.

Comment: Thanks. Are `\s` and `\d` not in ERE and BRE, but in PCRE?

Comment: Newer versions of bash have a globstar wild card as well, Its format is `**/` that indicate 'one or more sub directories'. Google resources are thin, this is probably a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/793715/1695680

Comment: @ThorSummoner This is well-documented in the bash manual, and there are [plenty of threads on this very site that mention `**/` and the [`globstar`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=globstar) option.

Comment: @Gilles I suggested as I noticed your answer lacks mention of it; thought you might like to add it. Or not. :)

Comment: Note that backreferences are supported in busybox `awk`: `echo aa | busybox awk -v re='(a)\\1' '$0 ~ re'` works there. The backslash handling is poorly specified in the POSIX spec of awk, so you see a lot of varying behaviour there.

Comment: The world of RegEx would have been a much better place if ancient folks had standardized RegEx syntax early enough before the chaos proliferated.

Comment: What an excellent answer! Thank you Gilles!

Comment: `sed -E` is recommended flag instead of `sed -r`. In the manual of sed 4.7, we can find: `(for portability use POSIX -E)`